# Não consigo achar o erro do codigo

Tags: python-3.x, string

Alguém poderia me indicar qual o erro deste código:

```
valor_hora = float(input('Valor da hora trabalhada: '))
qtd_horas_trabalhadas = int(input('Quantidade de horas trabalahadas: '))

salario_bruto = valor_hora * qtd_horas_trabalhadas
ir = salario_bruto * 0.11
inss = salario_bruto * 0.08
sindicato = salario_bruto * 0.05
salario_liquido = salario_bruto - (ir + inss + sindicato)

print(f'''+ Salário Bruto : R$ {salario_bruto:.2f}
          - IR (11%) : R$ {ir:2.f}
          - INSS (8%) : R$ {inss:2.f}
          - SINDICATO (5%) : R$ {sindicato:.2f}
          ----------------------------
          = Salário líquido : R${salario_liquido:.2f}''')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):  print(f'''+ Salário Bruto : R$
>   {salario_bruto} ValueError: Format specifier missing precision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro esta em:

```
- IR (11%) : R$ {ir:2.f}
```

e:

```
- INSS (8%) : R$ {inss:2.f}
```

Se você executasse separado iria notar qual falhou:

```
print(f'''+ Salário Bruto : R$ {salario_bruto:.2f}''')
print(f'''- IR (11%) : R$ {ir:2.f}''')
print(f'''- INSS (8%) : R$ {inss:2.f}''')
print(f'''- SINDICATO (5%) : R$ {sindicato:.2f}''')
print('----------------------------')
print(f'''= Salário líquido : R${salario_liquido:.2f}''')
```

Iria obter isto:

> ```
>     print(f'''- IR (11%) : R$ {ir:2.f}''')
> ValueError: Format specifier missing precision
> ```

Ou seja o `2.f` provavelmente deveria ser `.2f`

Comment: Isso mesmo...Falta de atenção.

Comment: @FabricioPaiva a dica que deixo com isto, é que nestes casos sempre teste um a um, se notar erros semelhantes, em testes isolados, não precisa ser no script principal, cria um script vazio e testa parte a parte, isolar as coisas é um bom caminho de entender o problema ;)

Answer (score -3):

Uma forma alternativa com **format**

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
valor_hora = float(input('Valor da hora trabalhada: '))
qtd_horas_trabalhadas = int(input('Quantidade de horas trabalahadas: '))

salario_bruto = valor_hora * qtd_horas_trabalhadas
ir = salario_bruto * 0.11
inss = salario_bruto * 0.08
sindicato = salario_bruto * 0.05
salario_liquido = salario_bruto - (ir + inss + sindicato)

print('''+ Salário Bruto : R$ {0:.2f}
          - IR (11%) : R$ {1:.2f}
          - INSS (8%) : R$ {2:.2f}
          - SINDICATO (5%) : R$ {3:.2f}
          ----------------------------
          = Salário líquido : R$ {4:.2f} '''.format(salario_bruto,ir,inss,sindicato,salario_liquido))
```

para maior legibilidade:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
valor_hora = float(input('Valor da hora trabalhada: '))
qtd_horas_trabalhadas = int(input('Quantidade de horas trabalahadas: '))

salario_bruto = valor_hora * qtd_horas_trabalhadas
ir = salario_bruto * 0.11
inss = salario_bruto * 0.08
sindicato = salario_bruto * 0.05
salario_liquido = salario_bruto - (ir + inss + sindicato)

print('''+ Salário Bruto : R$ {salario_bruto:.2f}
          - IR (11%) : R$ {ir:.2f}
          - INSS (8%) : R$ {inss:.2f}
          - SINDICATO (5%) : R$ {sindicato:.2f}
          ----------------------------
          = Salário líquido : R$ {salario_liquido:.2f} '''.format(salario_bruto=salario_bruto,ir=ir,inss=inss,sindicato=sindicato,salario_liquido=salario_liquido))
```

Comment: Então você acha 0, 1, 2, 3, etc melhor que os nomes das variaveis direto com `f"{}"`? Em que isto é melhor exatamente? Performance? Legibilidade?

Comment: não, mas nada impede de usar os nomes dentro do format.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento da segunda forma

Comment: E isto não lhe parece redundância? Porque como eu já disse, o efeito de `f"{}"` comparado ao format nos códigos apresentados seria o mesmo, você só está  "6" por "meia-duzia" e por fim está até deixando a legibilidade mais complexa ou se usar no proprio format o "nomeado"  (o que necessitaria de passar como objetos ou params, que tomaria mais tempo e complexidade) e por fim seria bem menos performático. Só existe uma unica vantagem no format sobre o `f"{}"`, retrocompatibilidade com Python2, de resto você apenas complicou o que era simples. Entenda que minha avaliação aqui é puramente técnica.

Comment: A única coisa que está escrito é "Uma forma alternativa com format". Em nenhum momento informa que é uma forma melhor ou mais performática. Antes de fazer um texto gigante querendo parecer que sabe tudo você deveria ler a resposta corretamente.

Comment: Não estou querendo parecer que sei tudo e nem nunca disse isto, estou aplicando um questionamento racional e lógico sem implicações pessoais, a unica questão aqui é"não lhe parece redundância?", porque é redundância, e fiz avaliação técnica sobre o que foi apresentado, que só seria útil se o código buscasse retrocompatibilidade com python2, mas raramente códigos python3 vão correr em py2, o que não adianta ter um pedaço retrocompativel. Por fim lhe apresentei os argumentos, lhe expliquei a parte técnica e você só presumiu que eu estou querendo "me achar", sendo que minha avaliação é só técnica

Comment: A pergunta é "Alguém poderia me indicar qual o erro deste código". Como isso responde a pergunta?

Answer (score -5):

Você precisa converter para `FLOAT`

```
print(f'''+ Salário Bruto : R$ {.format(float(salario_bruto:.2f)}
          - IR (11%) : R$ {ir:2.f}
          - INSS (8%) : R$ {inss:2.f}
          - SINDICATO (5%) : R$ {sindicato:.2f}
          ----------------------------
          = Salário líquido : R${salario_liquido:.2f}''')
```

Também sou inexperiente mas é para funcionar

Comment: Mas salario_bruto já não é do tipo float? A multiplicacao de um int por um float nao resulta em um float? type(salario_bruto) retorna float...